# SDK Here Navigate Flutter - Maneuver object with null values

Tags: flutter, here-api

I use SDK HERE Navigation version 4.5.4 for Flutter.

During navigation, I get the next maneuver index through `routeProgressListener` listener of `VisualNavigator` object, then I get the maneuver object in my route object.

But for each maneuvers of my route those parameters return `null` :

- `roadName`
- `roadNameLanguageCode`
- `roadNumber`
- `nextRoadName`
- `nextRoadNameLanguageCode`
- `nextRoadNumber`

But the parameter `text` return me a correct value.

My logs:

```
flutter: NAV - nextHereManeuver :
action ManeuverAction.rightTurn 
text Turn right onto Rue Roquelaine. Go for 112 m. 
roadType null 
roadName null 
roadNameLanguageCode null 
roadNumber null 
nextRoadName null 
nextRoadNameLanguageCode null 
nextRoadNumber null

flutter: NAV - nextHereManeuver :
action ManeuverAction.rightTurn 
text Turn right onto Boulevard de Strasbourg. Go for 96 m. 
roadType null 
roadName null 
roadNameLanguageCode null 
roadNumber null 
nextRoadName null 
nextRoadNameLanguageCode null 
nextRoadNumber null

etc.
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, during navigation you should take the `Maneuver` object from the `VisualNavigator's` `RouteProgress`, instead of taking it from the `Route` object instead. The maneuver's `text` taken from `Route` contains a localized description, but taking the same value from the `RouteProgress` is `null` during navigation.

Usually, I use the route for the route overview page to draw the route and show the maneuver list - and during navigation I take the maneuvers directly from navigator - as they are synced realtime with your current location. Here's some more code (in Dart) that shows how to get the content from `routeProgress`. It's taken from the HERE SDK's [GitHub](https://github.com/heremaps/here-sdk-examples/blob/master/examples/latest/navigate/flutter/navigation_app/lib/NavigationExample.dart) repo that contains some useful Flutter examples:

```
// Contains the progress for the next maneuver ahead and the next-next maneuvers, if any.
List<ManeuverProgress> nextManeuverList = routeProgress.maneuverProgress;

ManeuverProgress nextManeuverProgress = nextManeuverList.first;
if (nextManeuverProgress == null) {
  print('No next maneuver available.');
  return;
}

int nextManeuverIndex = nextManeuverProgress.maneuverIndex;
HERE.Maneuver nextManeuver = _visualNavigator.getManeuver(nextManeuverIndex);
if (nextManeuver == null) {
  // Should never happen as we retrieved the next maneuver progress above.
  return;
}

HERE.ManeuverAction action = nextManeuver.action;
String nextRoadName = nextManeuver.nextRoadName;
String road = nextRoadName ?? nextManeuver.nextRoadNumber;

if (action == HERE.ManeuverAction.arrive) {
  // We are approaching the destination, so there's no next road.
  String currentRoadName = nextManeuver.roadName;
  road = currentRoadName ?? nextManeuver.roadNumber;
}

// Happens only in rare cases, when also the fallback is null.
road ??= 'unnamed road';
```

So, basically, during navigation, you can get the `maneuver` like this (ignoring the `route` instance, which also contains maneuvers):

```
Maneuver nextManeuver = visualNavigator.getManeuver(nextManeuverIndex);
```

I would recommend to also take a look at the user guide for the Android flavor, it contains the same SDK logic, just the API interfaces are in Java/Kotlin instead of Dart. The explanations in [user guide](https://developer.here.com/documentation/android-sdk-navigate/4.5.1.0/dev_guide/topics/navigation.html#use-a-navigator-to-listen-for-guidance-events) for Android are quite helpful. It seems Flutter is still in beta, so the user guide is a bit limited in comparison to the native flavors.

Comment: It works if I get the next maneuver from visualNavigator.getManeuver(nextManeuverIndex) instead of the Route object. Thank you for your help.