# HERE SDK Navigate Flutter - Offset in next and next-next maneuver during navigation

Tags: flutter, here-api

I use SDK HERE Navigation version 4.5.4 for Flutter.

During navigation, I get the `RouteProgress` through `routeProgressListener` listener of `VisualNavigator` object.

This object contains `maneuverProgress` with the `maneuverIndex` which will be used to get the next `Maneuver` object in my route.

When the next `Maneuver` has a `ManeuverAction` property with `continueOn` value, an offset will be created on the progression.

I mean, when this `continueOn` maneuver will be terminated, the "next-next maneuver" returns will be actually the next maneuver et the "next maneuver" corresponds to the previous maneuver.

Thank you.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "an offset will be created on the progression"? The continueOn action just means you should continue on the current road into current direction ...

Comment: I will change my implementation to get the next maneuver as explain by yourself here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65087273/sdk-here-navigate-flutter-maneuver-object-with-null-values/65230509#65230509. Maybe this issue is linked with my implementation. And I will see if this offset appears again.

Comment: This offset was created by my wrong implementation to get the next maneuver from the Route object. Thank you Here team.